# Get the only one value out of the multiple matches using regex without re.findall

Tags: regex

I have a regex `(\bjack\b|\bjames\b)`
That matches jack and james but when they come together in a sentence i want only jack to be matched not james.

I want to use global flag for the regex so multiline wouldn't fit for the situation

Any suggestions on how to achieve this.?

Comment: `^[\w\W]*?\b(jack|james)\b`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works like a charm if you could explain that will help me in future

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried the regex for the following two sentences

jack and james

james and jack
 the first one matches jack and the second one matches james but in both it should match jack

Comment: No, it should not because regex finds either the first match or the last match, and the first alternation pattern that matches  "wins" and the subsequent alternatives are not considered/tried.

Comment: i was looking more of a prespective be it any position it should match jack only

Comment: Then search for `jack` only. Then search for `james` if need be.